# streaming data in bqplot visualization

Tags: python, bqplot

Other than running a loop in a latter notebook cell, how is it possible to stream data to bqplot? Does bqplot provide any periodic callback method for streaming data?

Also, does bqplot have a server to show the corresponding visualization (real-time visualization) as a standalone app? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Other than running a loop in a latter notebook cell, how is it
>   possible to stream data to bqplot? Does bqplot provide any periodic
>   callback method for streaming data?

I don't believe there is a periodic callback method but here is an example of streaming data. https://blog.jupyter.org/ros-jupyter-b7e82b5e1202

> Also, does bqplot have a server to show the corresponding
>   visualization (real-time visualization) as a standalone app? How can I
>   achieve this?

Yes. Voila will do this... https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila

Answer (score 0):

If your stream fills a local datasource you might be able to use the Play widget...?

https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html?highlight=play#Play-(Animation)-widget

I am also very curious to know the answer to this question!

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.