# What python visualization libraries support periodic callbacks in the browser?

Tags: python, plotly, seaborn, visualization, cartopy

The [`bokeh serve`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) feature allows [periodic callbacks](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/document.html) that execute **python** code in the browser window at specified intervals. Do any of the other **python** visualization libraries like `matplotlib` or `plotly` or `geoviews` support this type of interactive updating in the browser window? By browser, I mean in a browser as a web page ready for deploying over the network, not Jupyter notebooks during development.

Answer (score 1):

[Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) allows the interactive updating in a more general sense in that it isn't tied to any one python visualization library. You use ipywidgets to connect interactivity, output, and underlying Python code. For example, callbacks are discussed [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/499). You can see a number of examples in the [Voila gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/). I have some simpler examples [here](https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila).

Someone had similar questions about bqplot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58227228/8508004).